# Spring Webflux WebExceptionHandler not being Triggered by OptimisticLockingFailure

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have a GlobalExceptionHandler to catch all exceptions thrown and return a correct return code.
Everything works except when an OptimisticLockingFailureException happens and I have no clue why this is.

GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
class GlobalExceptionHandler : WebExceptionHandler {

    override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, throwable: Throwable): Mono<Void> = handleException(throwable)
            .flatMap { it.writeTo(exchange, HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(HandlerStrategies.withDefaults())) }
            .flatMap { Mono.empty<Void>() }

    private fun handleException(ex: Throwable): Mono<ServerResponse> = when (ex) {
        is EntityNotFoundException -> notFound(ex.message)
        is InvalidRequestException,
        is ReferenceKeyNotKnown,
        is InvalidContractTypeException -> badRequest(ex.message)
        is DuplicateKeyException,
        is TransactionException,
        is OptimisticLockingFailureException -> conflict(ex.message)
        else -> errorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.message)
    }

    private class HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(val strategies: HandlerStrategies) : ServerResponse.Context {
        override fun viewResolvers(): MutableList<ViewResolver> = strategies.viewResolvers()
        override fun messageWriters(): MutableList<HttpMessageWriter<*>> = strategies.messageWriters()
    }

}
```

the notFound, badRequest and errorResponse functions return a Mono with the correct statuscode and message.

Anyone that can help me out and point me in the right direction on why this isn't being triggered by the OptimistickLockingException?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason the exceptionhandler wasn't triggered was that we still had a .onErrorContinue step in our handler which logged the exception and nothing else. After moving the logging into the GlobalExceptionHandler and removing the onErrorContinue the GlobalExceptionHandler was working as expected